# Openshift script after deployment

Tags: python, node.js, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I m using openshift to deploy my app which uses python,mongodb and node.js.

After pushing all my code and data into server it is saying **service not available** when **rhc client** is closed.

Is that because i did not write **postdeploy** script?

Comment: Have you tried sshing into the application to see if node.js and python are both installed?  The python and node.js cartridges are both web cartridges, and you can only have one, I could see that leading to your issue if not properly resolved.

Comment: we could select both of it...and we tested..it works if rhc client is open

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you need the RHC open? It just sends a commands and then finishes executing.

The RHC client is a stateless means to send REST requests to the OpenShift Broker - it has absolutely no connection to the node running your app UNLESS you use RHC APP TAIL command or something like that. Do you mean when you ssh in the app stays open? Please don't forget we spin the app down after a day of no use and it will take a little while for it to spin up.

Is there a git hub repo of the app?

There is no need for a post-deploy script.

What do the logs for you application say. You can get to them either by doing RHC APP TAIL or by SSH'ing in to your application and going to ~/python-2.6/logs.